# Hadoop and Hive o

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I try to run a query on hive i get the following error:

```
 FATAL [IPC Server handler 14 on 59490] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1457495991188_0166_m_000000_3 - exited : Java heap space
```

The query is: (the variables $XXX are replace before execution)

```
FROM events_tmp 
INSERT INTO TABLE access PARTITION(day='$TODAY') 
SELECT $CFIELDS WHERE f0='access' AND f11 LIKE '$TODAY%' 
INSERT INTO TABLE access PARTITION(day='$YSTD') 
SELECT $CFIELDS WHERE f0='access' AND f11 LIKE '$YSTD%' 
INSERT INTO TABLE access PARTITION(day='$TMR') 
SELECT $CFIELDS WHERE f0='access' AND f11 LIKE '$TMR%' 
INSERT INTO TABLE downloads PARTITION(day='$TODAY') 
SELECT $IFIELDS WHERE f0='download' AND f36 LIKE '%dl%' AND f5 LIKE '$TODAY%'
INSERT INTO TABLE downloads PARTITION(day='$YSTD')
SELECT $IFIELDS WHERE f0='download' AND f36 LIKE '%dl%' AND f5 LIKE '$YSTD%'
INSERT INTO TABLE downloads PARTITION(day='$TMR') 
SELECT $IFIELDS WHERE f0='download' AND f36 LIKE '%dl%' AND f5 LIKE '$TMR%'
```

I added **export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=4096** to **/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-env.sh** but it doesn't change anything.... And there is also plenty of free RAM on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such error, you need to update following mapreduce heap size related properties in mapred-site.xml file.

```
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
             <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
            <value>-Xmx2048M</value>
</property>
<property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
           <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
           <value>-Xmx2048M</value>
</property>
```

Try it, it should help.

Comment: Thanks, is it for every nodes or just the hive one?

Comment: I tried but I am now getting this kind of errors: `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1457495991188_0222_m_000003_0: Container [pid=10139,containerID=container_1457495991188_0222_01_000007] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 262.2 MB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 3.7 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.`